# What books are Available for OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

As i am wanted to start with openlayer i wanted to know if any books or links are available on internet for same.I want to know WMS, WFS ,WPS.

Answer (score 3):

OpenLayers have very very good API docs and examples. Also I know only 2 books about OpenLayers:

- [API](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers-js.html)
- [Documentation](http://docs.openlayers.org/)
- [Examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/)
- [OpenLayers 2.10 Beginner's Guide](https://www.packtpub.com/openlayers-2-1-javascript-web-mapping-library-beginners-guide/book)
- [OpenLayers Webentwicklung mit dynamischen Karten und Geodaten](https://www.opensourcepress.de/index.php?26&backPID=178&tt_products=287)

Comment: Unfortunately the API docs are not very, very good. Reading the source code, although more dry, is more helpful.